# Why does LINQ to Entities string.Contains(string.Empty) match anything but string.Contains(string.Empty.ToLower()) match nothing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am writing a query for a repository service for an inventory table. FYI: We are using C# 7.0, EF 6, and we are using Moq for testing our queries.

I learned that when `string.Contains(...)`, which is by default case sensitive, is put into a LINQ query and then converted to SQL, the result is case **in**sensitive (found other SO posts to help with that and we'll deal with it), and I also found that the `string.Contains(...)` functions seems to have a quirk when the argument is `string.Empty` and is converted to lower case (found *no* SO posts about this).

Attempts to use the case-insensitive string.Contains(...) overloads are beaten back with an exception when LINQ to Entities attempts to convert to SQL, so I have to manually specify `column.Contains(argument.ToLower())` in order for both the the LINQ to Entities' SQL query to operate as intended *and* for the mocked-up unit test for case-insensitivity to pass.

**Problem:** If the argument is string.Empty, nothing is matched. The culprit is when then argument is converted to lower case.

This is not a roadblock (simply moving the `argument.ToLower()` check outside the query solved the issue, and it'd be a tad more efficient anyway), but I still want to know what's up.

```
public List<InventoryModel> FindByTrackingNumberSubstring( string substring )
{
    // (bad) matches nothing when argument is string.Empty
    //var query = _modelTable.Where( entity => entity.Tracking_Number.ToLower().Contains( substring.ToLower() ) );

    // (good) matches everything when argument is string.Empty
    string lower = substring.ToLower();
    var query = _modelTable.Where( entity => entity.Tracking_Number.ToLower().Contains( lower ) );

    return query.ToList<InventoryModel>();
}

// SQL for queries 1 and 2, respectively (stripped out SELECT and FROM stuff for brevity)
WHERE ((CASE WHEN (( CAST(CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__0), LOWER([Extent1].[Tracking Number])) AS int)) > 0) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT (( CAST(CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__0), LOWER([Extent1].[Tracking Number])) AS int)) > 0)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1)
WHERE ((CASE WHEN (LOWER([Extent1].[Tracking Number]) LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT (LOWER([Extent1].[Tracking Number]) LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~')) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1)
```

I did some checking and found that, in the LINQ to Entities' SQL query, that `string.Contains(string.Empty)` matches anything, and I found that `string.Empty.ToLower() == string.Empty` match anything, but put these two together and C# and LINQ to Entities diverge. In the former, `string.Contains(string.Empty.ToLower())` matches anything (as expected), but in the latter matches nothing..

Why?

Comment: Did you check the SQL translation for the two possibilities?

Comment: I don't know how to read that SQL. I can read and understand SQL, but not to this extent. I can see that they are different, but I don't understand what functionality is different. I am not familiar with SQL's `CASE`, but if it's anything like C#'s and C++'s, not a problem. But the `LIKE @p__linq__0` and `ESCAPE N'~'` and `CAST(CHARINDEX(morestuff))`? I don't know. I'm hoping that someone here can show me how to read it and help me understand the functional difference.

Comment: I think you have found a bug in the translation of `Contains` when combined with `ToLower` (and probably `ToUpper`). What SQL Engine/LINQ provider/EF Version are you using?

Comment: PS What is happening is that the first expression translates `ToLower` to SQL `LOWER`, translates `Contains` to `CHARINDEX` and e.g. T-SQL `CHARINDEX` says empty strings aren't found. The second expression translates `Contains` to a pattern match `LIKE %x%` which matches looking for empty strings.

Comment: @NetMage: We're working in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with SQL Server Express and EF 6. As for the LINQ provider...I don't know that one. The problem is in LINQ to Entities, so I presume that the provider would be the responsibility of EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would be a quirk of the SQL Server provider for EF in that when you perform the `.ToLower()` on the criteria and the field being compared it is recognizing the request as explicitly case-insensitive and replaces the LIKE query with the CHARINDEX comparison which does not handle empty strings in SQL Server the same way. The behaviour for case sensitivity will depend on the database engine, and in the case of SQL Server, the collation selected for strings in the database. Not sure why a LOWER(Tracking_Number) LIKE LOWER('%%') couldn't have been used.

Personally, when composing EF Linq expressions, my querying code will always inspect for IsNullOrEmpty on strings and not append `.Where()` conditions where an actual criteria has not been supplied. This way WHERE clauses are only applied for provided criteria.

I.e. If I trust the DB won't be collated case-sensitive:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(substring))
    query = query.Where(entity => entity.Tracking_Number.Contains(substring));
```

if I am concerned that the database could be collated case-sensitive:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(substring))
    query = query.Where( entity => entity.Tracking_Number.ToLower().Contains(substring.ToLower()));
```

Even there I would prefer to set a standard that Tracking_Number is always stored as a lower-case value if the database serves solely this application. The entity properties would enforce that any set value is lower-cased. (removing the need for .Tracking_Number.ToLower() in the queries.)

Comment: Interesting...Unfortunately I don't have control over the rules of the DB and we're in the middle of trying to transition to a more workable backend (we're actually moving *to* EF and away from hard-coded SQL query construction, which was not good, yet morbidly impressive in that it actually worked), so I cannot dictate the rules of casing nor the lookup logic, but you gave me an idea of how to alter the query to match everything without relying on `string.Contains` logic. Honestly this is among the least of our troubles :). Adventures in database migrations.

Anyway, thanks for the info.